# Odom does not move when roll-pitch-yaw is true when using ekf with imu data

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, xsens, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an xsens mti-7 imu. I plan to progress by integrating wheel odometry first and then gps, respectively. However, before doing these, I'm trying to do ekf using only imu with roll-pitch-yaw angles and roll-pitch-yaw velocity. At this point, the problems I encounter and the questions I want to ask are: (E : Error  Q: Question)

**E1:** parameters 1 for ekf file:

`imu0_config: [false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false]`

In this case, the odom frame makes slight movements and returns to the 0-0-0 position while the imu continues to move.

parameters 2 for ekf file :

`imu0_config: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false]`
In this case, the odom frame moves with the imu, but when it remains stationary, its angle decreases with a slight acceleration. Although there is no deviation and shift for imu, this happens for ekf.

**Q1:** What is the reason of this? Why can't I use the angle values for roll-pitch-yaw.

**Q2:** Why does ekf keep scrolling for 2nd parameters?

https://imgyukle.com/i/kgcHWN

https://imgyukle.com/i/kgcjzY

https://imgyukle.com/i/kgcOYq

https://imgyukle.com/i/kgcNPP

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390432/odom-does-not-move-when-roll-pitch-yaw-is-true-when-using-ekf-with-imu-data./) by [ndmrly](https://answers.ros.org/users/62987/ndmrly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-11-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-09**:
Hi @ndmrly, we can't see the pictures. Could you pls reload them.

**Comment by [ndmrly](https://answers.ros.org/users/62987/ndmrly/) on 2021-11-10**:
I updated it. @osilva

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2021-12-22**:
Please include:

1. Your full EKF configuration(s)
2. A sample message from every sensor input

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2022-01-14**:
Any update on this? Let me know if it can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your reply @Tom Moore . Sorry for the late reply. I solved my issue and I use r_l with rtk-gps. I got very god result. My problem was xsens driver and I fixed it. I close this now.

---

Originally posted by [ndmrly](https://answers.ros.org/users/62987/ndmrly/) with karma: 16 on 2022-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0